# Python Turtle nested polygons/growing shapes

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Basically we have to make this (20 units in between each polygon) using a function and a `for` loop:

[image: nested squares]

But it has to work with any sided polygon with any side length. So far I have:

```
import turtle
tess = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()
def draw_poly(t, n, sz):
    """
        Makes Turtle t draw an n sided polygon of size sz
    """
    for i in range(n):
        t.forward(sz)
        t.left(360/n)


sz = 20         #Length of sides
n = 4          #Number of sides

PosX = 0
PosY = 0
for i in range(5):
    draw_poly(tess, n, sz)
    tess.penup()
    PosX = PosX - 20
    PosY = PosY - 20
    tess.goto(PosX,PosY)
    sz = sz + 40
    tess.pendown()
wn.mainloop()
```

My problem is that it only works with squares, and any other amount of sides/side length makes it off-center. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a bit of trigonometry.  At the top of the script, add the line

```
from math import pi, tan
```

Then compute the new PosX, PosY as

```
PosX = PosX - 20
PosY = PosY - 20/tan(pi/n)
```